# file copy progress session data is null

Tags: php

am trying to get progress of all the files being copied.

```
    $qryStr = explode(",",$_POST['data']);
$timestamp=$_POST['timestamp'];
$size=sizeof($qryStr);
//echo $size;
$offset=100/$size;
$progress=0;
$_SESSION[$timestamp]=$progress;
session_start();
foreach($qryStr as $value) {

    $src = $value;
    $dest = "../home/tmp/";

    $cmd = 'scp '.$src.' '.$dest.'';
    sleep(1);
    $progress+=$offset;
    $_SESSION[$timestamp] = ceil($progress);
    var_dump($_SESSION[$timestamp]);
    $result = shell_exec($cmd);
 }
```

code to get progress stored in session

```
    session_start();

    var_dump($_SESSION['timestamp']);
     getProgress($_GET['timestamp']);

    function getProgress($timestamp) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$timestamp])) {
        echo json_encode(array("progress" => $_SESSION[$timestamp]));
      } else {
      echo json_encode(array("progress" => -1));
  }
 }
```

when i try to accesss the session data , am getting it as null. any problem in my script.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `$timestamp` in the following line,

```
$_SESSION[$timestamp] = ceil($progress);
```

Instead, use

```
$_SESSION['timestamp'] = ceil($progress);
```

Only then it will be available in `$_SESSION['timestamp']`, else will be in `$_SESSION['2013-10-28 14:33:00']`, something like that which is non-generic.

Comment: am passing the timestamp value from client. value is something like this  1382953967828

Comment: Ya, so you are saving data into `$_SESSION[1382953967828]` and trying to read from `$_SESSION['timestamp']`. That is the issue.

Comment: Do a `print_r($_SESSION);` inside `function getProgress`, it will give you clear idea. And also you can check whether data is saved into the particular SESSION variable you are trying to read from.

Comment: ok i agree that in var_dump($_SESSION['timestamp']); i made a mistake. but when i do print_r($_SESSION);   it gives me null

Comment: Also a clarification, do you assign value to `$_SESSION[1382953967828]` or `$_SESSION['1382953967828']`. i.e, `$timestamp` is integer or string ?